# How to handle file download errors with angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, download

Downloading files looks very trivial and there are many working solutions. *Working until the server says `401 UNAUTHORIZED`.* My requirements are rather natural:

- In no case the current window may be replaced.
- I don't want to open a new window, as it makes no sense.
- In case of an error, some message must be shown to the user.

I tried to use an `iframe` as a target of the link and hoped to be notified in case of an error. I see I was naive.

- I could imagine to place some script in the iframe which would notify main page `onunload`. It look a bit complicated so I'm asking first instead.
- I could ask the server about the outcome. This would surely work, somehow. But it's complicated too, as there's timing problem and the session is expired, so I'd have to circumvent this.

Comment: Have you tried `Blob` URLs for downloading files?

Comment: @OnurYıldırım No, never heard about them. From what I've just read, I'm rather sceptical. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [**`Blob`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object to trigger file download from javascript. This is introduced with the File API and still in *Working Draft* state. <s>So you'll have limited browser-support.</s> As of 2015, you have wide browser support for [Blob URLs](http://caniuse.com/#feat=bloburls) and [Blob Constructor](http://caniuse.com/#feat=blobbuilder).

```
<div ng-controller="appController" ng-app="app">
    <a ng-href="{{ fileUrl }}" download="file.txt">download</a>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

// Angular prepends "unsafe" tag in ng-href to prevent XSS
// so we need to sanitize this
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    // for Angular 1.0.x and 1.1.x, you should use urlSanitizationWhitelist
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|blob|ftp):/);
}]);

app.controller('appController', function ($scope, $window) {
    // Creating a Blob with our data for download
    // this will parse the URL in ng-href such as: blob:http...
    var data = 'some data here...',
        blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain' }),
        url = $window.URL || $window.webkitURL;
    $scope.fileUrl = url.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

See a [**demo fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/5gWFL/).

There are some libraries to extend browser support for this such as [**Blob.js**](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js)

*You should also check out [**FileSaver.js**](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) which also falls back to `data:URI`.*

Comment: It works nicely. I replaced your regex by `/^\s*(blob|https?|ftp|mailto|tel|file):/)` which simply adds "blob" to the whitelist. Your regex with `(|blob|)` looks very strange.

Comment: Thanks. I had `https?|blob|ftp` in my production code. Removed the rest to make it simple.. Fixed it above.

Comment: @OnurYıldırım: Sorry, I don't get it. How does this solve the problem of reporting an error when the server responds with a 401 ? This approach seems to assume that the data is already in the client. Did I miss something ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem, pls see the comments of the question and the other answer. OP says *"I see no way how to make the browser download a file I'm loading via `$http`."* With this kind of method, you can handle an error before serving the data as a download.

Comment: @OnurYildirim: I see. So, the idea is to get the content of the file via `$http` (handle any errors) and the enable downloading as a file using your method. It makes sense, thx for the clarification. Would this work for non-text files as well ? E.g. what would it take to download a PDF or XLSX this way ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem, in that case you would do `new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' })`

Comment: Worked for me! Soln is solid

Comment: The main issue with this approach is that the file has to be downloaded to the client before you can even show the link. While this may be hackish yet acceptable for really small files it would be unacceptable for downloads of large binary files.
Browser starts download of hundreds megabytes zipfile before I even click the link? No, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You could handle HTTP errors without it interrupting your controller / service logic by making use of HTTP interceptors.   When an error happens, handle it in an interceptor and then broadcast the error to an error handler, which could display an error to the user.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
    return {
       'request': function(config) {
        // same as above
        },

        'response': function(response) {
        // same as above
     }
  };
```

});

Comment: I'm afraid, I've tried it already. The problem is that it's not an `$http` request, but a separate `HTTP` request started by the browser on a click to `<a href=... download>`. I see no way how to make the browser *download* a file I'm loading via `$http`.