# read/download file using local absolute path

Tags: angularjs, jboss

I have one file which is stored at `D:/home/abc.pdf` locally.
I have to read this file using `AngularJs`

```
var path="D:/home/abc.pdf";
var doc = document.createElement("a");
doc.href = path;
doc.download = path;
doc.click();
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(path);
```

I am not able to download this file.Giving error like **Failed-Network error**
[image]

Comment: Go with [Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848522/how-to-handle-file-download-errors-with-angularjs)

Comment: I believe unless you're accessing your webapp itself from the same filesystem (`file://` URL) this will anyway not be allowed, as otherwise it would be a big, big, security risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is impossible since local files are protected. Else you would be able to manipulate the hard drive as you wanted just by running a local HTML page.

So : if you want to get a file from the computer's hard drive, you have to use an `<input>` field and ask the user to upload the file using it.